# How to invoke a function within a function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following function

```
function processData(data) {
  histograms = data[0].histograms.map(function(data) {
    return {
      title: data.sample,
      dataset: new Plottable.Dataset(),
      dataByThreshold: {},
      load: function(threshold) {
        this.dataset.data(this.dataByThreshold[threshold]);
      }
    };
  });
```

And the it is invoked like this

```
 processData(input_data);
```

with the following data:

```
var input_data = [{
  "threshold": 1.5,
  "histograms": [{
    "sample": "Sample1",
    "nof_genes": 26,
    "values": [{
      "score": 6.7530200000000002,
      "celltype": "Bcells"
    }, {
      "score": 11.432763461538459,
      "celltype": "DendriticCells"
    }, {
      "score": 25.823089615384621,
      "celltype": "Macrophages"
    }, {
      "score": 9.9911211538461551,
      "celltype": "gdTCells"
    }, {
      "score": 7.817228076923076,
      "celltype": "StemCells"
    }, {
      "score": 17.482806923076922,
      "celltype": "StromalCells"
    }, {
      "score": 29.335427692307697,
      "celltype": "Monocytes"
    }, {
      "score": 28.914959615384621,
      "celltype": "Neutrophils"
    }, {
      "score": 13.818888461538467,
      "celltype": "NKCells"
    }, {
      "score": 9.5030688461538464,
      "celltype": "abTcells"
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "threshold": 2,
  "histograms": [{
    "sample": "Sample1",
    "nof_genes": 30,
    "values": [{
      "score": 5.1335499999999996,
      "celltype": "Bcells"
    }, {
      "score": 16.076072499999999,
      "celltype": "DendriticCells"
    }, {
      "score": 46.182032499999998,
      "celltype": "Macrophages"
    }, {
      "score": 6.5895700000000001,
      "celltype": "gdTCells"
    }, {
      "score": 5.3218800000000002,
      "celltype": "StemCells"
    }, {
      "score": 53.643625,
      "celltype": "StromalCells"
    }, {
      "score": 85.1618225,
      "celltype": "Monocytes"
    }, {
      "score": 55.559129999999996,
      "celltype": "Neutrophils"
    }, {
      "score": 7.6717524999999984,
      "celltype": "NKCells"
    }, {
      "score": 6.3277800000000006,
      "celltype": "abTcells"
    }]
  }]
}];
```

My question is I want to create the similar function. But instead of
this **[Plottable](http://plottablejs.org/)** based

```
// dataset: new Plottable.Dataset(),
// this.dataset.data(this.dataByThreshold[threshold]);
```

I want to create the anonymous function something like this:

```
dataset2: new function () {},
load2: function(threshold) {
   this.dataset2.data(this.dataByThreshold[threshold]);
}
```

But when I tried that I get this message:

```
this.dataset2.data is not a function
```

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: which function are you trying to invoke, there is nothing called `data`

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Anon function that return `nof_genes`.This post is an attempt to solve this related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588069/how-to-make-label-in-histogram-respond-to-dynamic-user-input

Comment: Perhaps you want use it this way: `dataset2: {data: new function () {...}`}

Comment: @ArunPJohny I really appreciate if that post you can help?

Comment: I think your error should looks like 'this.dataset2.data is not a function'

Comment: @dullpointer:  I stand corrected. I updated the post.

Answer (score 2):

In the first example:

> ```
> this.dataset.data
> ```

The value of `dataset` is `new Plottable.Dataset(),`.

The return value of that is an object which has a `data` function, so you can call `data` as a function.

In the second example:

> ```
> this.dataset2.data
> ```

The value of `dataset2` is `new function () {},`.

The return value of that is an object, but you haven't given it a `data` property at all. (The people who wrote the `Dataset` function did give its return value a `data` property).

You need to define the function you are trying to call.

Comment: would you mind looking at this related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588069/how-to-make-label-in-histogram-respond-to-dynamic-user-input

Comment: How do you create `data` property in a function? I tried `data2: new function () {retire data.nof_genes};`

Comment: After the fact: `ref_to_object.data = something`. In advance? Put something on the prototype chain. (Which means learning JavaScript prototypal inheritance, which isn't something I'm going to try to explain in a comment).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking something like this,

```
      function dataset (){
         this.data=function(ip){
             //process your data here
             return ip;
          }
       }

      var dataset=new dataset();
      console.log(this.dataset.data('This is input data'));
```